# Rails, paperclip, react: don't save image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, paperclip

Have problem with save image via parerclip:
https://gist.github.com/pustovalov/9bb21936e1e1371a0da2ce3388877478

any suggestions how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer, need convert `base64` to img:

```
#app/models/item.rb

private
  def parse_image
  image = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(image_base)
  image.original_filename = "file.jpg"
  self.picture = image
end
```

http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/ruby-ruby-on-rails/handling-file-upload-using-ruby-on-rails-5-api